# Floor tile problem

Tags: linear-algebra

The 
foor of a rectangular room is covered with equal numbers of red and blue square
tiles. The room is x tiles wide and y tiles long. If only red tiles are placed around the
edge of the room and all of them are used for the boundary, nd all possible values of x
and y.

Comment: i apologise found this online, want to see if what i did was correct

Comment: If you found this online it is always good to provide the link of the source. Also you should tell us what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  given $x$ and $y$, can you make expressions for the number of border tiles and the number of non-border tiles?  It often helps to draw a picture-it is easy to get the corners wrong.

Comment: 2(x-2)+2y = (x-2)(y-2)

Comment: would that be correct?

Comment: @Daniel:  That is right.  Expanding, we have $xy-4(x+y)+4=0$  If $x=y$, this becomes $x^2-8x+4=0$ which has no solutions.  We can then assume $x \gt y$ and solve for $x$, getting $x=\frac {4y-4}{y-4}$ and look for values of $y$ which give an integral result.